# Is there a way to look what steps will be executed on delete row from Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a query, that executes 5 minutes. I want to reduce this time. For doing that I have to know what triggers will be triggered and what rows from another tables will be deleted on cascade. There are no a lot of rows in the target table. So is there a way to look what will be executed on row delete (Oracle DB) ?

Query looks like:
`DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME where FIELD = 'VALUE';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all the triggers of `DELETE` event on the table, use following query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_TRIGGERS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>'
   AND TABLE_OWNER = '<YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME>'
   AND TRIGGERING_EVENT LIKE '%DELETE%';
```

To find all the tables from where data will be deleted by `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint, use the following query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
   AND DELETE_RULE = 'CASCADE'
   AND R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = (
        SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
          FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
         WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>'
           AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
    );
```